# Convert Strings in Array to Datetime '%Y'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime

I have a python array:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

ray = ['01.01.88', '01.01.99', '01.01.87', '01.01.89', '01.01.96',
       '01.01.95', '01.01.95']

ray = np.array(ray)
type(ray)
ray
```

I'd like to convert the strings in this array to an array of dates in the `%Y` format.  If possible, please do not convert `ray` back to a list, I need to keep it as an array.

Comment: Does `.22` mean 2022 or 1922?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 2022

Comment: If you want to keep it as an array, you need to convert it to a valid `dtype`.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output? Do you want strings/numbers?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a vectorial transformation, I would suggest to use pandas's [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
import pandas as pd
ray = pd.to_datetime(ray).values
```

Output:

```
array(['1988-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1999-01-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1987-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1989-01-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1996-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1995-01-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1995-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

*Notes. I'm assuming a `MM.DD.YY` format, if `DD.MM.YY` use `dayfirst=True` as parameter of `to_datetime`. Also, using `values` and not `to_numpy()` on purpose to avoid the unnecessary copy of the underlying array.*

To have the years as strings:

```
out = pd.to_datetime(ray).strftime('%Y').values
```

Output:

```
array(['1988', '1999', '1987', '1989', '1996', '1995', '1995'],
      dtype=object)
```

As integers:

```
out = pd.to_datetime(ray).year.values
```

Output:

```
array([1988, 1999, 1987, 1989, 1996, 1995, 1995])
```